# Spring JPA hibernate -Repeated transactions in the API making it slow

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I am working on an API in spring - JPA - Hibernate application.
API receives List of Orders which needs to be persisted one by one.

Controller method is like below

```
bulkUpsert(@RequestBody Orders orders){
  for(Order order:orders.getOrders()){
       saveOrUpdateOrder(order);
  }
}
```

Service Method is below

```
@Transactional
saveOrUpdateOrder(Order order){
   //do processing and call dao methods to save/update
}
```

here is my spring config

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
      p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="defaultTimeout" value="${jdbc.defaultTransactionTimeout}"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

web xml:

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
```

Now the issue that I have observing is that as the no of orders passed keep on increasing ,the time to complete the API is exponentially increasing.I wasn't expecting this as I am commiting the orders one by one.
IF first 100 orders take around 10 seconds then 900th-1000th orders take more than 1 minute.

Now If I add entitymanager.clear() just after calling saveOrUpdateOrder in the loop of controller method(bulkUpsert), api becomes electric fast.

Though I am happy that issue is resolved but I am baffled as my understanding doesn't match with what has happened.I was expecting that when transaction commits it will flush all the things and everything will start all again for the next transaction.

Is it not so ?

Does entities still remain in the session even when transaction commits ?

Comment: In theory you are correct. However Spring Boot by default enables Open EntityManager In View pattern which gives you 1 entitymanager for the whole request processing. This is also why you so the behavior you are seeing. You could disable the pattern (set the property to `false` in your `application.properties`) to get the behavior you expected to have. However that might break other parts of your application that (unknowingly) rely on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you are correct, however as Spring Boot by default enables the [`OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration.java#L216) which enables the [open entitymanager in view pattern](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-open-session-in-view-anti-pattern/). This in turn leads you to a single `EntityManager` per request.

This explains the behavior you see as you expect to get a new and fresh `EntityManager` per transaction but instead the pre-registered `EntityManager` is re-used.

You can solve this by disabling the `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor`. Do this by setting the `spring.jpa.open-in-view` to `false` in the `application.properties` file. This might, however, lead to issues with other code which, probably unknowingly, depends op the open entitymanager in view behavior.

Comment: I was also thinking that Requires_new should resolve this issue but it didnt.It was as slow as it was before.

Comment: Well my bad. That indeed doesn't solve it, as the single entitymanager is still there. You will have multiple transactions but still a single entitymanager. I've removed that from my answer.

Comment: So my question is even if only one entitymanager is there why should it slow down the API.If I check the heap space that never increased exponentially with the increase of the no of orders...Or is it something impacting hibernate only ?

Comment: That is how ORM works. It is because there is one entitymanager it slows down. There are dirty checks done for each object in the first level cache (the`EntityManager`), and it does this with each `flush` or query to the database. And as you add more and more entities to a single entitymanager this becomes slower and slower. Now when you call `clear()` you basically drop everything from that entitymanager and no checks need to be done. Which is why that makes it fast.

Comment: I was expecting that it drops everything when transaction commits as it will flush all the stuff and synchronize DB ?

Comment: No it doesn't, it only synchronizes the state, it doesn't remove the managed entities from the `EntityManager`.

Comment: though i dint try the workaround..accepting this answer as it answed the question raised by me.thanks.

Comment: @M.Deinum Is it possible to disable `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` for a single controller or controller method? Or is there an annotation which will call `.clear()` after the transaction or to use a separate entity manager per service method call/per transaction?

Comment: Please don't ask a new question in comments, instead ask a new and proper question.